# Contact form 7 (Загрузка фото)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form7

Форма из пяти шагов, на 4 шаге загрузка трёх фото, если выбрать большие картинки, то форма долго их грузит, но на следующий шаг пропускает, и после нажатия кнопки отправки формы, происходит ошибка, так как картинки не загружены...

как можно отменить переход на следующий шаг, если картинки еще не загрузились? или возможно ли сделать что-то типо состояние загрузки фото?

Comment: В contact form 7 нет никаких шагов, насколько мне известно . Покажите  настройки формы.

Comment: Могу только предположить, что картинки превышают разрешенный размер загружаемых на сервер файлов. Клиент при загрузке не может сразу определить размер файла, поэтому в любом случае начнет загрузку. И вот если файл слишком большой, то сервер его просто не сохраняет. Соответственно и к форме добавить не сможет. Размер загружаемого файла настраивается на сервере. По умолчанию, если я не путаю, это 2 МБ. Нужно увеличить этот лимит.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы проверить максимальный размер для загружаемых файлов установите плагин WordPress phpinfo()
В консоли выбрать пункт настройки, потом php info и там найти параметр upload_max_filesize это и есть максимальный размер загружаемого файла.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно долго работали с Contact form 7.
Мои рекомендации:

Увиличиваем максимальный размер загружаемых файлов

**Вариант 1**
Открываем на стороне хостинга файл php.ini, находим строку upload_max_filesize и post_max_size, правим размер. К примеру:

```
post_max_size = 20M
upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

на

```
post_max_size = 99M
upload_max_filesize = 99M
```

**Вариант 2**
Открываем .htaccess веб-сервера Apache, правим параметры:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 99M
php_value post_max_size 99M
```

**Другие варианты**
Существует еще несколько вариантов, в зависимости от вашего сервера и других особенностей.

Работая долгое время с WP, настоятельно не рекомендуем использовать этот плагин. Это один из самых популярных плагинов для заражения вашего сайта. Случаи заражения очень часты!